# Woocommerce - Getting the order item price and quantity.

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, items, orders

Using Woocommerce 2.6.8 , I can't get the Order Item Data information as described in the [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1186-1218) and [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39409201/2193349).

All I want is to get the Line Item price and Quantity, which should be as simple as:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order_items = $order->get_items();
 foreach ($order_items as $items_key => $items_value) {  
           echo $items_value['name']; //this works
           echo $items_value['qty']; //this doesn't work
           echo $items_value[item_meta][_qty][0]; //also doesn't work
           echo $items_value['line_total']; //this doesn't work
   }
```

Looking closer at what gets returned returned

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Sample Product 1
        [type] => line_item
        [item_meta] => 
        [item_meta_array] => Array
            (
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _qty
                        [value] => 1
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _tax_class
                        [value] => 
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _product_id
                        [value] => 8
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _variation_id
                        [value] => 0
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _line_subtotal
                        [value] => 50
                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _line_total
                        [value] => 50
                    )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _line_subtotal_tax
                        [value] => 0
                    )

                [8] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _line_tax
                        [value] => 0
                    )

                [9] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [key] => _line_tax_data
                        [value] => a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

This is all using documented Woocommerce methods, why is the information I need stored in this `item_meta_array`?

Does anyone know how I can get that information?

Preferably using documented methods as opposed to a crude hack of looping through the `item_meta_array` until I find the key I'm looking for.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

> **Update *(For WooCommerce 3+)***

Now for the code you can use [`WC_Order_Item_Product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) (and [`WC_Product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)) methods instead, like:

```
## For WooCommerce 3+ ##

// Getting an instance of the WC_Order object from a defined ORDER ID
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

// Iterating through each "line" items in the order      
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
    $product        = $item->get_product();

    $active_price   = $product->get_price(); // The product active raw price

    $regular_price  = $product->get_sale_price(); // The product raw sale price

    $sale_price     = $product->get_regular_price(); // The product raw regular price

    $product_name   = $item->get_name(); // Get the item name (product name)

    $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity

    $item_subtotal  = $item->get_subtotal(); // Get the item line total non discounted

    $item_subto_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Get the item line total tax non discounted

    $item_total     = $item->get_total(); // Get the item line total discounted

    $item_total_tax = $item->get_total_tax(); // Get the item line total  tax discounted

    $item_taxes     = $item->get_taxes(); // Get the item taxes array

    $item_tax_class = $item->get_tax_class(); // Get the item tax class

    $item_tax_status= $item->get_tax_status(); // Get the item tax status

    $item_downloads = $item->get_item_downloads(); // Get the item downloads

    // Displaying this data (to check)
    echo 'Product name: '.$product_name.' | Quantity: '.$item_quantity.' | Item total: '. number_format( $item_total, 2 );
}
```

**Update:** Also all the following [`WC_Abstract_Order` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html) allow to get order items data with various interesting options like:

```
// Getting an instance of the WC_Order object from a defined ORDER ID
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

// Iterating through each "line" items in the order
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
     ## Option: Including or excluding Taxes
     $inc_tax = true; 

     ## Option: Round at item level (or not)
     $round   = false; // Not rounded at item level ("true"  for rounding at item level)

     $item_cost_excl_disc = $order->get_item_subtotal( $item, $inc_tax, $round ); // Calculate item cost (not discounted) - useful for gateways.

     $item_cost_incl_disc = $order->get_item_total( $item, $inc_tax, $round ); // Calculate item cost (discounted) - useful for gateways.

     $item_tax_cost       = $order->get_item_tax( $item, $inc_tax, $round ); // Get item tax cost - useful for gateways.

      $item_Line_subtotal = $order->get_line_subtotal( $item, $inc_tax, $round ); // Get line subtotal - not discounted.

     $item_Line_total     = $order->get_line_total( $item, $inc_tax, $round ); // Get line total - discounted

     $item_Line_tax       = $order->get_line_tax( $item ); // Get line tax

     $form_line_subtotal  = $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item, $tax_display = '' ) // Gets line subtotal - formatted for display.
}
```

*Thanks to @Casper for his comment*

---

Also [`WC_Data` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) can be used to get order item data as an unprotected array or to get a specific nested or custom meta data value from a specific meta key:

```
// Getting an instance of the WC_Order object from a defined ORDER ID
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

// Iterating through each "line" items in the order
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $order_item_data      = $item->get_data(); // Get WooCommerce order item meta data in an unprotected array
    print_r( $order_item_data ); // display raw data

    $item_meta_data = $item->get_meta_data(); // Get order item nested and custom meta data in an unprotected array
    print_r( $item_meta_data ); // display raw data

    $item_value     = $item->get_meta('meta_key'); // Get specific order item custom or nested meta data value from a meta_key
    print_r( $item_value ); // display raw data (can be a string or an array)
}
```

This code is tested and works.

> Method `get_item_meta()` is deprecated and has been replaced by [**`wc_get_order_item_meta`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html) and it's not anymore a method **but a function** with some parameters:

> ```
> /** Parameters summary
> ```

```
 * @param mixed $item_id
 * @param mixed $key
 * @param bool $single (default: true)
 * @return mixed
 */
```

> ```
> wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, $key, $single = true );
> ```

---

> Prior versions of woocommerce (from 2.4 to 2.6.x)

You can use [**`get_item_meta()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_item_meta) WC_Abstract_order method, to get the order metadata (the item quantity and the item price total).

So your code will be:

```
// Getting the order object "$order"
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
// Getting the items in the order
$order_items = $order->get_items();
// Iterating through each item in the order
foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $item) {
    // Get the product name
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    // Get the item quantity
    $item_quantity = $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', true);
    // Get the item line total
    $item_total = $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_line_total', true);

    // Displaying this data (to check)
    echo 'Product name: '.$product_name.' | Quantity: '.$item_quantity.' | Item total: '. $item_total;
}
```

This code is tested and fully functional.

Reference: [Class WC_Abstract_Order Methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_item_meta)

Comment: `get_total()` is not available within the `Wc_Order_Item` class. See: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html

Comment: @BasvanDijk But `get_total()` method is available for `WC_Order_Item_Product` which is the main Class involved for order "line" items, since WooCommerce 3… see: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_total

Comment: @LoicTheAztec maybe you meant `$item_cost_excl_disc = $order->get_item_subtotal( $item, $inc_tax, $round )` and so on, as `get_item_subtotal` and the other stuff is based on methods from `WC_Abstract_Order` and so they can be accessed only as `$order->get_...`.

Comment: @DavideCavestro Oups yes I forgot `$order->`… Thanks.

Comment: Following returns **unit price**: `$order->get_item_total( $item, ... )` since it divides by quantity.

Answer (score 10):

Item price can get from `order` object by below code

```
$order->get_item_total( $item );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see this documentation for woocommerce Line item in order class.
[Here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.7---Order-and-Order-Line-Item-Data#line-item-product)

You can call total for get the total order cost.
If you want to retrieve the single item cost by taking the **product_id**

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$Price = $_product->get_price();
```

Or you can do this.

```
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
```

this get the product price today, not the price when made the order.
so if a order is made with unit price 10 and then the unit price is changed you will get the new price. the order still has the old "original" order price..

Comment: For an order item, this will break any compatibility with the many plugins that dynamically change the checkout/order price from the originally set regular and sale prices. For better cross compatibility, I believe it's better to use `$order_item->get_subtotal()` or `$order_item->get_total()`.