# Get refunded orders and refunded order items details in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I see when I look at an order it will show the specific item that was refunded if the whole order wasn't.

Is there a way to find using the `WC_Order_Item_Product` if an item was refunded?  Also, is there a way to get the discount amount that shows up below the item in the order view?

I'm currently doing it manually but if there is a function for it already, I would rather use it.

Comment: Updated the answer with that important detail: you can use `$item->get_meta('_refunded_item_id');` to get the original item ID that has been refunded

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get refunded orders you could use some dedicated [`WC_Order` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_refunds) like the following ones that have Item Id as argument:

```
$item_qty_refunded = $order->get_qty_refunded_for_item( $item_id ); // Get the refunded amount for a line item.

$item_total_refunded = $order->get_total_refunded_for_item( $item_id ); // Get the refunded amount for a line item.
```

You can access an array [`WC_Order_Refund`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Refund.html) Objects for this order using [`get_refunds()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_refunds) method:

- For each refund, you can use the [`WC_Order_Refund`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Refund.html) methods.
- For each refund, you can access items using `WC_Abstract_Order` method [`get_items()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_items) that will give you the refunded items for the current Order refund.
- Each refund "line" item is a [`WC_Order_Item_Product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) (with negative values in general) see this related answer: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

So you can use the following example code:

```
// Get the WC_Order Object instance (from the order ID)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get the Order refunds (array of refunds)
$order_refunds = $order->get_refunds();

// Loop through the order refunds array
foreach( $order_refunds as $refund ){
    // Loop through the order refund line items
    foreach( $refund->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){

        ## --- Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods --- ##

        $refunded_quantity      = $item->get_quantity(); // Quantity: zero or negative integer
        $refunded_line_subtotal = $item->get_subtotal(); // line subtotal: zero or negative number
        // ... And so on ...

        // Get the original refunded item ID
        $refunded_item_id       = $item->get_meta('_refunded_item_id'); // line subtotal: zero or negative number
    }
}
```

**To get the order items discounted values** that appear in admin order edit pages you will use the following code:

```
// Get the WC_Order Object instance (from the order ID)
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Loop through the order refund line items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
    $line_subtotal     = $item->get_subtotal();
    $line_total        = $item->get_total();
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax();
    $line_total_tax    = $item->get_total_tax();
    
    // Get the negative discount values
    $line_discount     = $line_total - $line_subtotal; // (Negative number)
    $line_discount_tax = $line_total_tax - $line_subtotal_tax; // (Negative number)
}
```

Related Answers:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [Woocommerce - Getting the order item price and quantity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711160/woocommerce-getting-the-order-item-price-and-quantity/40715347#40715347)

Comment: How to get refunded tax amount for line item ?

Comment: what could be the issue, when these ways do not work? I get a refund but the refund itself has no items? and the other way mentioned with $order->get_qty_refunded_for_item( $item_id ); always returns 0 for order items which are refunded???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `get_qty_refunded_for_item( $item_id )` or `get_total_refunded_for_item( $item_id )` returns 0 use `absint()`.

```
$item_qty_refunded = $order->get_qty_refunded_for_item( $item_id ); // Get the refunded amount for a line item.

$item_total_refunded = $order->get_total_refunded_for_item( $item_id ); // Get the refunded amount for a line item.
```