# Check if an order contains any refund in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

is it possible to check an order if it contains any refund programatically?

I want to display a specific text if that is the case. So far im checking if its cancelled:

```
if($order->has_status('cancelled') echo "display text";
```

But since the order status does not change if just a single item in an order of multiple items is refunded, I cant figure how to do this.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WC_Order the method `get_refunds()` like:

```
if( sizeof( $order->get_refunds() ) > 0 ) {
    printf( 'Order id %s has some refund', $order->get_id() ); 
}
```

Or as a custom conditional function:

```
function has_refunds( $order ) {
    return sizeof( $order->get_refunds() ) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if( has_refunds( $order ) ) {
   // Do something
}
```

Related answer thread: [Get refunded orders and refunded order items details in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490697/get-refunded-orders-and-refunded-order-items-details-in-woocommerce-3/52491796#52491796)